# How Can I change Label Text in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to change label text in an input field;

```
var check =  $("#name_label").find(".nameText").text("Malcom"); 
alert("check" + check);
```

here is  my HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="NameList" id="name_label">
<label for="name_label">
<div class="nameText">&nbsp;</div>
</label>
```

right now it return object instead of changing the text. Please help.

Comment: Your label is not inside the input (an `input` can't have any children). Try `$("#name_label").next().find(".nameText").text("Malcom");`

Comment: You don't need an extra div in there. You could potentialy give an id to the label.

Comment: @Daniel I think op is referencing the `input` with that ID and trying to find the label inside the input field (which it isn't).

Comment: Sorry but your question is bit confused. You want append an <input type="text"> inside that label after mark the checkbox?

Comment: @putvande - Yeah .. i think OP is a bit confused here :-) .. There are mixed problems here.

Answer (score 1):

change your code with

```
 $("[for='name_label']").find(".nameText").text("Malcom")
```

Answer (score 0):

The label is the next element after input but **not inside** input

```
$("#name_label").next('label').find('.nameText').text("Malcom");
```

To then check it you have to get the text inside (and not by puttinf the text in, that will result in an html object)

```
var check = $("#name_label").next('label').find('.nameText').text();
alert("check " + check);
```

See code example below

```js
$("#name_label").next('label').find('.nameText').text("Malcom");
var check = $("#name_label").next('label').find('.nameText').text();
alert("check " + check);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="NameList" id="name_label">
<label for="name_label">
<div class="nameText">&nbsp;</div>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

select your label and then its inner div and change its html like this

```
$("label[for=name_label]").find(".nameText").html("Malcom");
```